# Help needed for basic C input and output

Tags: c

I need to get two inputs- hexadecimal address and number of bits- and then I need to print out the index and the offset of the address.

Thus, If the inputs are 20 and 0x0FF10100, the output should be 0x0FF1 for index and 0100 for the offset.

```
int bits, index, offset, count;
short addr[10], addr2;


printf("# of bits: ");
scanf("%d", &bits);

index = (bits / 4) + 2;
offset = 10 - index;

printf("Integer (in hex): ");
scanf("%hi", addr);
```

Then I need to output the index which is (20/4)+2 = 7 that means first 7 characters of the address.  And the rest as offset.

I could not use printf i tried many times. But i could not fix I hope someone could help

Thanks everyone.

For output I tried to use

```
while (count < index)
{
    printf("", addr[count], addr[count]);
    count++;
}
```

It did not print out anything...

then I tried many variations of that and I got error. I dont know what to use to output..

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you could not use printf?  You mean the source code won't compile for you?

Comment: isn't that obvious by meaning cant use.. I tried but I got error

Comment: @TipiTip: Compile error? Please post it.

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>` ? Also what is `count` initialized to? It could be that you're never entering the `while` loop.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `printf("", addr[count], addr[count]);` to print anything. There's nothing in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but your printf call is using an empty string instead of a format string.  You can see the various format specifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Always check the return value of `scanf` if you intend on using the input; it will return the number of items that it has successfully scanned. If you ignore the return value, you risk attempting to read indeterminate values, which means your program has undefined behaviour.

Also, in your second call to `scanf`, you aren't asking for a hexadecimal integer, you are asking for a short integer (`h` means short, and `i` means integer). If you want to scan a hexadecimal short integer, you need to use `hx`, but this also means you need to provide the address of an `unsigned short`, rather than a plain `short`.

```
int bits, index, offset, count;
unsigned short addr[10], addr2;

printf("# of bits: ");
if (scanf("%d", &bits) != 1)
{
    // could not scan
    // handle scan error here. Exit, or try again, etc.
}

index = (bits / 4) + 2;
offset = 10 - index;

printf("Integer (in hex): ");
if (scanf("%hx", addr) != 1)
{
    // could not scan
    // do whatever makes sense on scan failure.
}
```

If you are reading into consecutive elements of your `addr` array, you might want the following instead:

```
printf("Integer (in hex): ");
if (scanf("%hx", &addr[count]) != 1)
{
    // could not scan
    // do whatever makes sense on scan failure.
}
```

Finally regarding your use of `printf`: the first argument to `printf` tells it how to print the provided data. You have given it an empty string which means `printf` is not told to print anything. Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
printf("%d: %hx", count, addr[count]);
```